# Sound Design fundamentals for different genres

Tags: genre, design

Hi all,

Just wanted to know if anyone was aware of any good sites where people have written about/reviewed the different sound design fundamentals for different genres? Like comedy, horror, drama etc. I know that there are different subcategories for each genre but what I want is a site(s) that discuss how the different genre's differ when it comes to sound design. I hope I am clear in my question.

I know of a few like filmsound.org, designsound.com etc. But are there others?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Soundworkscollection.com is another great one. Also, check out the links section on the right hand side of designingsound.org (below the archives).  Most of everything I would mention/recommend is listed there. VERY extensive list. Also, a lot of those questions get discussed on the Yahoo group sound_design. I would recommend signing up for that too.

With all of that, you can pick and choose which ones you like the best, then set up an RSS aggregator (like Google Reader) and sign up for the RSS feeds from the sites you like. Then they all feed into one place, and you have a personalized one-stop-shop for learning about sound design!